# same jquery function on the same page

Tags: jquery

hi guys im building a site with a image file preview using a form

this is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#ImageFile").on("change", function(){
            var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
            if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
            if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
                var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file
                reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                    $("#uploadImagePreview").css("display","block");
                    $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
                    $("#imagePreview").css("max-height","100px");    
                    $("#imagePreview").css("height","100px"); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

it works perfect but i have 3 forma that use this function on the same page but only works on the first one i test it when building the forms and works on each but after adding one more the previews stop and the third do the same with the second what im doing wrong or how do you think i can solve it

this is the html

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile"  class="supercell">Shield</label>
     <input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="uploadImagePreview">
             <div id="imagePreview"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with `id` - `ImageFile` in the same page? If yes then it will work for only first one.. so better change it to `class`... and event handling of `change` on `class` itself.. `id`s must be unique in `HTML`

Comment: so instead of using #imagepreview to .imagepreview right

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)